# How can i make so when i click a button it will resolve a promise, and if i click again it will wait untill the previous promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, settimeout

```js
  let msg = "Done";
  function promise() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Done");
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
  async function func1() {
    msg = "Pending";
    console.log("Starting...");
    const a = await promise();
    console.log(a);
    msg = a;
  }

  async function func2() {
    console.log("Queued");
  }

  async function call() {
    if ((msg) === "Done") {
      func1();
    } else {
      func2();
    }
  }
```

```html
<h1>PROMISE</h1>
<input onclick="call()" type="button" value="Click me " />
```

I added this piece of code into func2(), it runs func1() after the previous promise is resolved, but it also runs it immediately after click. How can i do so it only runs after previous promise is resolved.

```
func2() {
  console.log("Queued");
  await func1();
  func1();
}
```

EDIT:
Guys! I solved this problem using Date().getTime() method, and adding "clicks" variable. The result is almost the same. But the way of doing it is different. When i click its immediately starts executing promise, but i wanted it to wait untill the promise from previous click is finished and only then start executing a new promise. I think there has to be some other simpler solution.

```js
 let msg = "Done";
  let clicks = 0;
  let t1;
  let t2;
  let timeout = 0;
  let txt = "";
  function promise() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Done");
      }, 2000 * clicks - timeout);
    });
  }
  async function func1() {
    clicks = 1;
    timeout = 0;
    txt = "";
    msg = "Pending";

    let time = new Date();
    t1 = time.getTime();
    const a = await promise();
    let taym = new Date();
    let now = taym.getTime();
    createDiv(now, t1, txt);
    msg = a;
  }

  async function func2() {
    clicks++;
    let time = new Date();
    t2 = time.getTime();
    timeout = t2 - t1;
    const a = await promise();
    let taym = new Date();
    let now = taym.getTime();
    txt = " and " + (now - t2) + " ms after last click";
    createDiv(now, t1, txt);
  }

  async function call() {
    if (msg === "Done") {
      func1();
    } else {
      func2();
    }
  }

  function createDiv(a, b, c) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "Created " + (a - b) + " ms after main click" + c;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
```

```html
<h1>PROMISE</h1>
<input onclick="call()" type="button" value="Click me " />
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but what are you expecting `a` to be set to? The `.then()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: What function does the click call? Is there supposed to be an `onclick` in the HTML?

Comment: what does any of the code you've shown have to do with "clicking a button"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Sorry for inaccuracies, i fixed them now. Click calls "call()" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below does what I think you want

resolving to the event, just to show that the timeStamp shown in the second click is the first click timeStamp, because that's what the promise resolves to in this example

Not sure how useful this code is though

```js
const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  document.getElementById('bang').addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('first click');
    resolve(e);
  }, { once: true });
})
promise.then(e => {
  console.log(e.timeStamp, e.type, e.target.id);
  document.getElementById('bang').addEventListener('click', e => {
    promise.then(e => {
      console.log('not the first click');
      console.log(e.timeStamp, e.type, e.target.id);
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="bang">Resolve the promise</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't solve directly my problem, but it helped me to come up with an idea to add clicks property, and also use Date().getTime() function. I solved the problem by changing the promise's  setTimeout function's milliseconds each time the click event happens. And chane it using the difference between t2=getTime and t1=getTime. But i think there has to be some other simpler solution to this problem.